# regex for date not working

Tags: regex, date

I am using below regex for date in format dd-mm-yyyy

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$
                                                     ^^^^^
```

With this regex, I believe I can only use 19xx and 20xx years. I want user can enter from 20xx till 99xx.

For that I tried below, but its not working.

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.]([20-99])\d\d$
                                                     ^^^^^^^
```

I don't know regex much, but based on `0[1-9]` I thought `([20-99])` will work.

What changes should I make in above regex so that I can enter 2000-9999 as year?

Comment: The year part is not the problem. `[20-99]` will not work, you can only define certain chars (like `[a-zA-Z9-0]`).

Comment: **downvoters**  Whats wrong in this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.]([2-9][0-9])\d\d$
```

or

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.][2-9]\d\d\d$
```

or

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.][2-9]\d{3}$
```

Comment: you wanted 20-99, so that would be [2-9][0-9]

Comment: thanks... its wokring... will accept answer after some time... SO is saying "You can accept an answer in 9 minutes"

Comment: how can I validate `12:00 PM` using regex?

Comment: AM/PM would likely be [AP]M